# Listener for new file created in workspace in vscode extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was looking through the vscode api, and I was wondering if there exists a type of listener event that sees that a file was created in the current workspace folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemWatcher) for this, for instance if you wanted to know about the creation of `.txt` files in the current workspace:

```ts
let folders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
if (folders) {
    let watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(
        new vscode.RelativePattern(folders[0], "*.txt"));
    watcher.onDidCreate(uri => console.log(`created ${uri}`));
}
```